# How to set webrtc to use STREAM_MUSIC to play voice on Android?

Tags: android, webrtc

Webrtc use STREAM_VOICE_CALL to play the voice default .
How to set webrtc to use STREAM_MUSIC to play voice on Android ?
Is that impossible ??

Comment: Any solution you have come across?

Comment: Please checkout whether https://stackoverflow.com/a/67800829/5309486 answer satisfy your needs.